# POSIX Threads, args, arrays, and type-casting

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading

Hello you beautiful people you. I'm trying to alter some Histogram code that computes averages of a grayscale images pixels' gray ranges. Sorry for the word vomit, but just so you know what I'm doing.

So, we know that pthread_create is defined as follows:

```
pthread_create (thread,attr,start_routine,arg)
```

and if we have more than one argument, we should put them in some sort of array or some sort of data structure. So I created a void *args[4] that I had intended to store all my parameters into.

the following is the definition of the compute_histogram function

```
compute_histogram(image_t *image, int num_buckets, histogram_t *histogram)
```

which will need to be changed to accommodate my call found in the below code block.

```
for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++) {
    rc = pthread_create(&thread[t], &attr, compute_histogram, args);
}
```

I have previously assigned the attr state to joinable. In args however, I'm trying to include all of the previously mentioned parameters, and including the thread id as well. Below I show how I'm attempting to place my parameters into my args array.

```
args[0] = (void *)image;
args[1] = (void *)num_buckets;
args[2] = (void *)histogram;
```

args[3] would be changed to whatever t it is in the for loop to give the thread an id so I can keep track of it, and I would do some partitioning of the task by thread in the compute_histogram function. When I compile, however, I get errors saying that I cannot cast image or histogram to pointer types, and it warns me against doing so with num_buckets. There are a few more errors due to my attempt to call compute_histogram, but I will worry about those once I figure out how to get my arguments passed in.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The function pointer type passed to pthread_create must be `void*(*)(void*)`.

Comment: My rusty 8-ball says you need to say `args[2] = &histogram`. There's no need to cast it to `void*`.

Comment: For the OP, why did you choose against using structures? Then you could have a structure containing all the actual types, no casting needed. Dynamically allocate one such structure, initialize it, and pass the pointer to the threads. The dynamic allocation part is important, especially if you create multiple threads passing multiple different arguments. Using the array, all threads will have the exact same pointer, leading to data-races.

Comment: @ZachThompson I would not go that far, (OK, if I did I would get suspended again:).  Its is, however, very easy to get misled by the HUGE number of totally hopeless 'Intro to Threads' sites.  The ones with arrays for everything, join() everywhere and all the rest of the usual rubbish.

Comment: is the whole, use pthread_exit(NULL) at the end of main instead of return 0 also rubbish? I learned threads for a class and the tutorial I found here - https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/ - said to do that. Sorry for the late response, once I got my program working I went straight to bed.